# Default value Timefield Django

Tags: django, timefield

I have a timefield and I would like to set up a default value.

I tried `time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(10, 0))`

but I have the error

> cannot cast type time without timezone to timestamp with time zone

Any idea ?

Comment: is timezone settings active in your project? So, have you this in your settings.py `USE_TZ = True` ?

Comment: Yes I have @kamilyrb

Comment: Do you need timezone info in your project?

Comment: Yes since I have users in different country

Comment: using Datetimefield more efficient for you then. Because 03:00 in Paris is something like 23:00 in New York, but in the previous day. It doesn't make much sense to have a timezone-aware time-only field